# Using Sendkeys and VBA to paste ASCII special characters in an external program

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I have inherited a set of Excel macros that take information from a spreadsheet and utilize Sendkeys to paste the information into our AP software. I have been debugging various issues mostly related to the timing of key-presses and the sequence they're entered. One issue that I have been unable to find a complete workaround for is converting characters such as % and ( ) into a paste-able format to be passed into our AP software. I have found various pieces online that explain using the CHR() function or regex. I have been unable to implement any of these answers into my application. These characters typically only affect our description line the current means of pasting the description passes through the following sections.

This captures the information where the description information is located and performs some very basic cleaning.

```
 JEDescription = (Trim$(Range(cellDescription).Value))
   JEDescription = Application.Substitute(JEDescription, "(", " ")
   JEDescription = Application.Substitute(JEDescription, ")", " ")
```

That is passed into our "write_description" which determines which of our descriptions is used, it can either be a line by line description or a blanket description for a batch.

```
Private Sub write_Description(arrDetailJE() As DetailJE, i As Integer)
    If TF_JE_Line_Description = True Then
        SendKeys arrDetailJE(i).JE_Line_Description, True
        Sleep lngSleep
    Else
       SendKeys JEDescription, True
       Sleep lngSleep
    End If
    

End Sub
```

I need a way to pass special values, most importantly % and ( ) through to the external program, via sendkeys. I found a UDF that works in theory but have been unable to implement it into my current macro.

```
Function CleanTrim(ByVal S As String, Optional ConvertNonBreakingSpace As Boolean = True) As String
  Dim X As Long, CodesToClean As Variant
  CodesToClean = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, _
                       21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)
  If ConvertNonBreakingSpace Then S = Replace(S, Chr(160), " ")
  For X = LBound(CodesToClean) To UBound(CodesToClean)
    If InStr(S, Chr(CodesToClean(X))) Then S = Replace(S, Chr(CodesToClean(X)), "")
  Next
' ""& added to preserve leading 0's in text fields
  CleanTrim = ""&WorksheetFunction.Trim(S)
End Function
```

Something similar that allows the macro to detect keys that would interrupt Sendkeys and pass them  through is the desired outcome.

Comment: Why don't you put your information into the clip board with VBA and use sendkeys only to paste (Ctrl + V) in the AP software? That way you don't have any issues with special characters?